# Show that $A= ([0,\sqrt2] \cap \Bbb Q ) \subset \Bbb Q $ is not compact.

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

We have $\Bbb  Q$ equipped with the Euclidean Metric.

Show that $A=([0,\sqrt2] \cap \Bbb Q ) \subset \Bbb Q  $ is not compact.

How would you go about showing this?

You can make on open cover $\{O_n\}= ((-\infty, \sqrt2 -\frac1n) \cap \Bbb Q)$ for $n\ge1$

$ A \subset {O_n}$

How would you show there is no finite subcover?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

What can you say about the sequence (and its subsequences)

$$\left\{\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n\right\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\subset A\;\;?$$

Comment: They converges to 1?

Comment: @user113867: rather $\mathrm e^{-1}$

Comment: No, it converges to $\;e^{-1}\notin A\;$ , so...?

Comment: Not fully sure what you're getting at. Is a subspace compact iff all cauchy sequences converge?

Comment: @user113867: [Every compact metric space is complete, though complete spaces need not be compact.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space#Some_theorems)

Comment: @DonAntonio: if completeness is something you are suggesting to use, I believe that it is a bit too strong here. The problem can be asked to students with still basic knowledge of topology, and without any knowledge of metric-space-related stuff at all.

Comment: Not at all, @Ilya : as with any *metric space* , a subset is compact iff every (infinite) sequence in it has a convergent subsequence.

Comment: NO @user113867: in order to be compact $\;A\;$ has to fulfill what I wrote in my past comment: every infintie sequence in it has to have a convergent (within $\;A\;$ , of course) subsequence.

Comment: @Ilya actually the module I'm taking covered Metric Spaces first, then Topologies, and then revisited Metrics to define compact metric spaces.

Comment: @DonAntonio So this sequence doesn't have any convergent subsequence because the sequence itself doesn't converge, as $e^{-1} \notin A $ ? Is that right?

Comment: Well, yes @user113867, though I'd rather argue: since the sequence is a Cauchy sequence (it converges in $\;\Bbb R\;$, say) which does *not* converge, then any infinite subsequence also doesn't converge, which means the set is not sequentially compact $\;\iff\;$ it is not compact, as we're in a metric space.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there was a finite subcover. Then $A \subset (-\infty, \sqrt2 -\frac1n) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ for some $n$. However, $[\sqrt2 -\frac1n, \sqrt{2} ] \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset$, which contradictions the definition of $A$.

Comment: Are you saying that $n$ is finite?

Comment: Yes, if $O_{n_1},...,O_{n_k}$ is finite open cover of $A$, then let $n = \max(n_1,...,n_k)$.

Comment: @copper.hat I upvoted.  Your answer answers the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, whether you already know that images of compact spaces under continuous maps are compact, but in case you do, this criterion may be sometimes easier to use than coming up with open covers. In particular, any continuous function on a compact attains its extremal values. Let $X := \mathbb Q\cap[0,\sqrt2]$ and define $\iota:X\to \mathbb R$ be the embedding map. Clearly, it is continuous and clearly $\sup_{x\in X}\iota(x) = \sqrt 2$, however for no $x\in X$ it holds that $\iota(x) = \sqrt2$, so $X$ is not compact.

Perhaps, in the current situation it is not much different from other solutions provided, however I think this trick is just worth keeping in mind for the future problems in topology.

Answer (score 1):

It is not sequential compact hence not compact

$x_n={[\sqrt{2}n]\over n}\in [0,\sqrt{2}]\cap\mathbb{Q},x_n\to\sqrt{2}\notin [0,\sqrt{2}]\cap\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: But $x_1 = \sqrt2 \notin [0, \sqrt2] \cap \Bbb Q $

Comment: $x_1=1$.................... $[x]=x-\{x\}$ where $\{x\}$ is fractional part of $x$

Answer (score 1):

Let $O_{n_1},\ldots,O_{n_k}$ be a finite subcover, with $n_1<\cdots<n_k$. Then
$$\left(\sqrt2-\frac{1}{n_k},\sqrt2-\frac{1}{n_k+1}\right)\cap \mathbb Q$$
is nonempty and contained in $[0,\sqrt2]\cap \mathbb Q$ but disjoint from $O_{n_1}\cup\cdots\cup O_{n_k}$, so $[0,\sqrt2]\cap \mathbb Q\nsubseteq O_{n_1}\cup\cdots\cup O_{n_k}$.

Answer (score 1):

If a subset $A$ of $\mathbb R$ is compact, then it is also closed. In particular, if a ssequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in}\subset A$ converges to $x$, then $x\in A$. Let
\begin{align}
x_1=&1\\
x_2=&1.4 \\
x_3=&1.41 \\
x_4=&1.414 \\
x_5=&1.4142 \\
etc.
\end{align}
I.e., 
$$
x_n=\frac{\lfloor10^n\sqrt{2}\rfloor}{10^n},
$$
Clearly $x_n\to\sqrt{2}$, as $|x_n-\sqrt{2}|<10^{-n}$, and $\sqrt{2}\not\in A$. Hence $A$ is not compact.

Comment: Essentially, you seem to use the same approach as I did without explicitly mentioning it. I believe you shall prove the relevance of *If a subset of $\Bbb R$ is compact, then it is also closed* to the setting of OP.

Comment: What is that notation you are using for the numerator? When I tried to create a sequence like this I could only come up with $(\sqrt2 - \frac1n $ but this has elements $\notin A$ . I was looking for a way to come up with something like this!

Comment: It is the integer part of $10^n\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @user113867: it is handy to remember that any real number can be approximated by rational ones (that's actually can be considered as one of definition of reals): just think of the decimal expression of real numbers. Whenever you truncate it, you obtain a rational number which better and better approximates the real one. This truncation is what Yiorgos wrote explicitly here.